# open messages to a contact at bottom of list

Tags: contacts, htc-sense, sms

When I open my messages list with a contact <strike>(I presume this is the same across all androids, and not my htc legend)</strike> it has the message history with that contact...if you have just received a message from them, the new message is at the bottom and you always have to scroll to it...is there a way to make it so that the new message is focused? or that newer messages are in view by default or by sorting?

**Edit**
Seems to be a HTC Sense messages app bug...Anyone with HTC Sense not have this problem?

Comment: Default messaging app? I don't see this with default or handcent app on htc incredible.

Comment: I have an HTC Incredible and I don't have this problem. I do, however, occasionally have to scroll all the way through the messages, and have not figured out why.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

HTC Desire stock Froyo rom. I don't see this behaviour. Default message app shows the last messages by default. If I use the contact app (tab with message conversations) I see the more recent messages at the top.

I can confirm that like Kevin M on rare occasions the messaging app will show the earliest messages instead and I have to scroll to the bottom. That's a bug for sure, I've seen it only a couple of times though...

Comment: I'm on 2.1 so maybe it will be resolved once the 2.2 update is provided by my carrier.

Answer (score 2):

HTC provided the Froyo (2.2) update for my phone for my carrier which I've now installed and it is no longer a problem. Furthermore, the messaging app in 2.2 is a lot better than 2.1, so happy user all round here.